# Multiple Recurring Memberships one Contribution. How to remove 1 membership

Tags: civimember, contributions, recurring

We have the option for a user to have their main membership and a second optional add on membership.

We want the user to be able to cancel the optional membership whenever they want.

Currently have built a process to end membership by cancelling recurring contribution via the api. This works well for single memberships or if they want to cancel both.

BUT I want them to just cancel the add on.

I have tried simply removing the 'contribution_recur_id' from the membership, but when the billing cycle comes round the full amount is charged and the add on membership is reinstated.

Any ideas or examples of how to manage this?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set the membership status to Cancelled and update the recurring/subscription amount either from CiviCRM or payment gateway based on payment processor you are using.

Comment: Thanks. I am using stripe. I can ammend the amount, but not sure how/where civi associated the membership with the recurring contribution ID (as I cancel the membership and set the ID to none!